# QT how to detect the systray area for creating systary pop up windows

Tags: qt, systray, popupwindow

i need to create/design QT systray popup windows , i was thinking about creating custom windows  that 
derived from QDialog , so it could look better then the ordinary "Information,Warning,Critical styles"
my question is how can i detect the position of the desktop systray ,so how could give the popup windows
the look and feel of a systray popup

Answer (score 6):

You might use the rectangle given by `QSystemTrayIcon::geometry()` to know precisely the position of the desktop systray. The geometry method gives the position in screen coordinate of the system tray icon.

See the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qsystemtrayicon.html#geometry) for more information.

Comment: I'm afraid that, at best, this only works on some platforms. In my Mint/GNOME environment, this returns a `QRect(0, 0, 22, 22)`. The icon looks like it's 22×22, so it looks like we can get its size, but not its position, which is what's really required. (My tray icon is three-quarters towards the right of the screen, so (0, 0) definitely isn't correct.)