# Qt tray icon window

Tags: qt

I am using `QT.QSystemTrayIcon` to create a tray icon.

When clicking on a tray icon, I need a window to opens right above the icon (in the bottom right corner). How can I do this?

Comment: Please use a better syntax for your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QT how to detect the systray area for creating systary pop up windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848416/qt-how-to-detect-the-systray-area-for-creating-systary-pop-up-windows)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Do you mean open a window such as QMainWindow or QWidget above the tray icon?

You need to get a `QDesktopWidget` using `QApplication::desktop()`, then query that QDesktopWidget's `screenGeometry()` function to determine the screen dimension, then create a window and position it appropriately in the right bottom corner based on the coordinates obtained from `screenGeometry()`.

Comment: This won't put the window near the tray icon if the taskbar has been moved to a different location (side or top of the screen), and is also likely to fail in multi-monitor situations.

Comment: Also, different platforms put tray icons in different places.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to open the window aligned with the icon (as the built-in volume control does), take a look at the **[manual](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsystemtrayicon.html#geometry)** for this:

```
QRect QSystemTrayIcon::geometry()
```

<sub>Ok, I'm answering 4 years later, because I found this question today, trying to solve the same problem.</sub>

Note: This is working well on Win, tested on XP, 7 and 8 but, as pointed by @MichaelScheper, this isn't working on Mint/GNOME. Feedback on other platforms is welcome.

Comment: I'm afraid that, at best, this only works on some platforms. In my Mint/GNOME environment, this returns a `QRect(0, 0, 22, 22)`. The icon looks like it's 22×22, so it looks like we can get its size, but not its position, which is what's really required. (My tray icon is three-quarters towards the right of the screen, so (0, 0) definitely isn't correct.)

Comment: @MichaelScheper thanks for the feedback. I really couldn't test it in many platforms. In Windows it worked well in XP, 7, 8, providing both size and position. Are you using any customized icon dock, or are you using the default menu bar? In a couple of weeks I need to port some apps to Linux, I'll try to do some tests then.

Comment: No worries—I'll be porting the other way soon. :-) I'm using PyQt Python bindings, but otherwise, I'm pretty sure my code is pretty ordinary: While initialising a `QDialog`, I'm doing `self.trayIcon = QSystemTrayIcon(self)` `self.trayIcon.setIcon(myIcon)` `self.trayIcon.show()` `logging.debug('trayIcon geometry: %s', self.trayIcon.geometry())`. I just tried it in Windows, and it does indeed return coordinates there. I suppose for now I'll use them where available, and let you know if I find a Linux solution.

Comment: For linux I'm using QCursor.pos() (python PyQt).  I'm assuming the mouse is on the tray item, which I've found to be true for KDE.  I then look at weather pos.x() < window.width() or pos.y() < window.height() to figure out whether the tray is and choose the appropriate x +- width, y +- height  for the window placement.  A bit of hack, but I haven't yet found an alternative (yet).

Answer (score 3):

```
 void main_window::create_tray_icon()
 {
    m_tray_icon = new QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon(":/icon.png"), this);

    QAction *quit_action = new QAction( "Exit", m_tray_icon );
    connect( quit_action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(on_exit()) );

    QAction *another_action = new QAction( "Do something", m_tray_icon );
    connect( another_action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(on_do_something()) );

    QMenu *tray_icon_menu = new QMenu;
    tray_icon_menu->addAction( another_action );
    tray_icon_menu->addAction( quit_action );

    m_tray_icon->setContextMenu( tray_icon_menu );

    m_tray_icon->show();
  }
```

Comment: This looks like it adds a menu, not a window. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by a window. My first answer refers to a context menu that popups where you can add several actions.

If you want to have a small information window with a message in it like in Windows, you should use [QSystemTrayIcon::showMessage](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qsystemtrayicon.html#showMessage). There you can popup a message, set the duration of this message and set an icon for it.